# Any Text after quotation mark disappearing onclick in text box

Tags: javascript, jsp

Text box is dynamic so it can be edited and saved again at any time.  It is acting strange. If I add a text with a quotation mark and save it when I refresh the page everything seems fine but when I click the text box to edit it hides everything after the quotation mark but if I don't make any changes and click out of the box everything appears again.

```
    <logic:equal name="readOnly" value="false">
<tr class="item_snippet editorLink">
    <td class="editable col_description"><div class="static-text"></div>
        <input class="edit-field" name="description" maxlength="100" placeholder="<bean:message key="rootcause.text.addRootCause"/>"/></td>
    <td class="editable col_typeID"><div class="static-text"></div>
        <logic:notEmpty name="rootCauseTypeListing">
        <select class="edit-field" name="typeID">
        <logic:iterate id="type" name="rootCauseTypeListing">
        <option value="<bean:write name="type" property="key"/>"><bean:write name="type" property="value"/></option>
        </logic:iterate>
        </select></logic:notEmpty></td>
    <td></td>

this.setItemEvents = function(o){
        o.addEvents({
            'mouseover': function(){
                o.addClass('hover');
                if (oToolbar){
                    instance.showInlineToolBar(o);
                }
            },
            'mouseout': function(e){
                if (e.relatedTarget == oToolbar){ return;}
                o.removeClass('hover');
                if (oToolbar){
                    instance.hideInlineToolBar(o);
                }
            },
            'click': function(e){
                o.addClass('hover');
            }
        });

        o.getChildren('td.editable').each(function(td){
            var t = td.getFirst('.'+class_staticText);
            var f = td.getFirst('.'+class_editField);

            // date picker fields initial setting: display dateClone instead of static text
            /*
            if (f && f.hasClass(class_datePicker)){
                var dateClone = f.getNext('.' + class_datePicker);
                t.setStyle('display', 'none');
                dateClone.setStyle('display', 'block');
            }*/

            // general events
            td.addEvents({
                'mouseover': function(){
                    td.addClass('hover');
                    td.setStyle('cursor', 'text');
                },
                'mouseout': function(e){
                    //if (e.relatedTarget == oToolbar){ return;}
                    td.removeClass('hover');
                },
                'click': function(e){
                    instance.onEditMode(td);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                },
                'keydown': function(e){
                    instance.setTabMove(e, td);
                }
            });
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the HTML / CSS to show how it's being rendered on the client-side, so we can try to run it as a snippet and see what's going on?

Comment: @Aswin Ramakrishnan I just took a snap shot of rendered HTML. Check it out.  Thanks!